# Springboot test with different properties per location

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

My question in short:
How can I run a test with different properties in different environments?

Long version:
I have written a JUnit-Test which is annotated at the class top like following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest( classes=RunServer.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT )
@TestPropertySource(locations="file:conf/application-junit.properties")
public class MyDbTest {...
```

In the current **conf/application.junit.properties** there is the statement for the database connection on port 5400.

But now I found that I do not only run the tests locally but also on another machine like a Jenkins where the database port is located at 5500.

I do have a properties file with the right port which is located at **conf/application-jenkins.properties**.

Now I wonder how to set the proper value for the **@TestPropertySource(locations=...)** in the source code?

By the way. This is all no problem for non test code execution where I only set as argument

`java -jar myjar.jar --spring.config.location=<PATH_TO_PROPERTIES_FILE>`
My properties files are not within the classpath. They are set as absolute file paths.

Thank you all for any help.

Comment: See if you can use `spring.profiles.include` in this case. Just a hunch. Have not tried it personally

Answer (score 4):

You should not specify that :

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="file:conf/application-junit.properties")
```

That hardcodes the `junit` Spring Boot profile in the test class.

Instead, you should execute the tests according to the profile set as `mvn test` is executed such as :

```
mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=junit

mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=jenkins
```

`application-junit.properties` or `application-jenkins.properties` would be automatically used to create the ApplicationContext according to the `spring.profiles.active` value set.

Comment: ...just two years later... some thought: I can have several profiles activated, can't I? So which properties would be used?